# How to accept multiple string variables from a file

Tags: java

I'm trying to read data from a file and write it into an array. I believe the multiple string variables are what is throwing me off.

I've tried using scan.NextLine but it still doesn't work.

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException
{
    File f = new File("inData.txt");

    House[] list = new House[7];
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(f);
    int count = 0;

    while (scan.hasNext())
    {
       list[count] = new House(scan.next(), scan.next(), scan.next(), scan.nextInt());

       count++;
    }
```

The file is from a notepad file called "inData.txt". Here's a picture: of the file.
[Notepad Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/63rZx.jpg)

The error message I'm getting is "java.util.InputMismatchException".

Here is my code for the House class.

```
public class House
{
    private String houseID, town, zipCode;
    private int price;

    public House(String houseID, String town, String zipCode, int price)
    {
        this.houseID = houseID;
        this.town    = town;
        this.zipCode = zipCode;
        this.price   = price;
    }
```

Comment: You're not showing what the file looks like, what errors you're seeing ... please tell and show the details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that Scanner() reads values delimited by whitespace, and you're expecting each line to parse into 4 values.  This will work for the first four lines of your input file, but then you have two lines that technically have 5 values in them because the City values on those lines contain whitespace.  This is going to get your Scanner out of sync and you're going to get bad behavior and/or results.

If you can't control the format of your input, then you're going to have to do something more sophisticated than what you're doing here.  Scanner() can't know to ignore the space between the two words in the City values on lines 5 and 6.

My way to deal with this would be to ditch Scanner, read in each line as a single String, and apply a regular expression to the line to extract the individual fields from the line of input.  You could also do a `split()`, and assume that if you get 5 elements back, then elements 2 and 3 should be combined into a single element.  That's kinda hacky though...what if you have a City name with 2 spaces in it?.

Comment: Oh, very true. I completely forgot I had to include town names that contained only one word. Thank you!

Comment: I don't know why you accepted the other answer.  He's wrong.  You don't need the `scan.nextLine()` call.  The `next()` and `nextInt()` calls WILL pass over newlines.  They're just whitespace.  I don't even care if you mark my answer as the right one, but please don't accept an answer that is actually incorrect.  I ran your exact code over your data, and it works fine if you don't have those spaces in the 5th and 6th lines.  Your code was just fine as is.  Please keep S.O. pure and don't allow it to stand that you've accepted an answer that is wrong. - you can take your approval back.

Comment: steve I posted that 'other answer' before he gave the format for the text document, and without knowing what it was like the other one would have been completely acceptable

Comment: Well, it's better.  Now you've just copied what I said, which at least is correct.  But now there are two identical answers, one of which does not provide as much information as the other and was possibly stolen from the other.  I don't care about the points, but as both of your original answers were wrong, it's sneaky and wrong to now put a totally different answer in place that is not what the upvotes or the checkmark were in response to. - your answers were wrong...you should have just deleted them.

Comment: Thank you very much guys, I marked Steve's as the correct answer as he clarified that my program works fine without the `scan.nextLine()` call as long as I don't have any whitespace.